# I've installed dot net core on mac, but didn't find "dotnet" command

Tags: macos, command, installation

Today I've just downloaded "dotnet-dev-osx-x64.1.0.0-preview1-002702.pkg" and installed it. After that I tried "dotnet" command in my terminal, nothing printed.

I also tried Spotlight searching, seems nothing found.

Where is this package installed at all?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The key thing is you need to locate the file dotnet.exe, then create a new Symbolic link to create a new shortcut link to that dotnet.exe file in the usr/local/bin folder. Sometimes you see this error "/usr/local/bin//dotnet: File exists", it means the link already exists in that folder (and it's normally a faulty one), to fix that you need to go to that folder and delete the link.

After you have located the dotnet.exe file, in my case it's in the '/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet'  folder. Create a new symbolic link for it using this command:

ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/

Done! You can run the "dotnet" command now...Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the fix, just had the same issue and this resolved it. Thanks Hung Vu !

Comment: @Hung Vu Please could you explain this line a bit? "ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/ " where and how in my terminal should i run that command? in any directory?

Comment: It works perfectly, I used Command+Shift+G to open the find dialogue box · Input the following in the search box: "/usr/local/bin"

Comment: The "In" creates command creates a short to given executable `In -s sourcepath targetpath`. Read more [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/297721/how-to-create-and-use-symbolic-links-aka-symlinks-on-a-mac) .

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATE FOR .NET Core 6**

It looks like the binary location has been changed to `/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet` but also, the link is broken, since `/usr/local/bin/dotnet` exists...so I had to delete the old symlink, and replace it like below.

The "new" link would be:
`ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: thank yoouu!!! I have tried to fix this for weeks now, this one did it for me

Comment: This answer is actually not correct, at least in Arm Mac (M1/M1Pro/M1Max, etc). There are 2 versions in this case. `/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet` is the Arm one, and `/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet` is the x64 version, as per official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos#path-differences

Comment: @Meligy - I have an M1 Mac and that's how I resolved it. But I can modify the answer above to include better information.

Comment: @NovaDev it may depend on if you are running an arm64 terminal. I forget exactly how to check it. But your terminal may be running x86-style under rosetta, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I found it was installed at `usr/local/share/`

So added this to the end of my PATH variable

:/usr/local/share/dotnet

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, but slightly different error message:

### `It seems the symlink source '/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet' is not there.`

```
$ brew install dotnet-sdk
==> Downloading https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/8509554d-61b4-43b8-b934-ad2e679ce1
Already downloaded: /Users/devinrhode2/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/2b854af3d17e907f13c66328d3144bde572daea671923126eec05783659f1b7f--dotnet-sdk-6.0.102-osx-x64.pkg
==> Installing Cask dotnet-sdk
==> Running installer for dotnet-sdk; your password may be necessary.
Package installers may write to any location; options such as `--appdir` are ignored.
Password:
installer: Package name is Microsoft .NET SDK 6.0.102 (x64)
installer: Upgrading at base path /
installer: The upgrade was successful.
==> Purging files for version 6.0.102,8509554d-61b4-43b8-b934-ad2e679ce18f,aa565a52b909b3133ef6763bb2868a4
Error: It seems the symlink source '/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet' is not there.
```

Turns out, this symlink source file really does *not* exist.
But, I do have a `/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64` directory.

This is odd. When I run `arch` in my terminal, it shows `arm64`. So I'm not sure why dotnet is adding not adding the `arm64` version of dotnet (`/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet`)

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/114509

I also had this issue opening up a zsh terminal - it just prints "zsh: killed" and vscode terminal wouldn't open. Only normal terminal or iTerm would open, and those would print "zsh: killed"

Eventually I uninstalled all homebrew packages, and ran homebrews uninstall script, to completely uninstall homebrew. I reinstalled a handful of packages: git, curl, etc. Still had zsh issue, but, I ended up doing `brew install zsh` and using brew-installed zsh instead of Monterey default zsh (I just upgraded macOS, so that probably caused the zsh issue).

I also had this snippet sitting in my shell profile startup script:

```
export DOTNET_ROOT="/usr/local/opt/dotnet/libexec"
```

This was likely causing my issue.

After all this cleanup, I ran `brew install dotnet-sdk` and it worked fine the first time without any warnings or errors.

Answer (score 0):

Usage: dotnet [options]
Usage: dotnet [path-to-application]

Options:
-h|--help         Display help.
--info            Display .NET information.
--list-sdks       Display the installed SDKs.
--list-runtimes   Display the installed runtimes.

path-to-application:
The path to an application .dll file to execute.
anasmahdi@Anass-Air ~ % dotnet --version
A fatal error occurred, the folder [/usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not contain any version-numbered child folders
anasmahdi@Anass-Air ~ %

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).