# dotnet: command not found in Mac

Tags: macos, .net-core

So I downloaded NET Core 2.1 SDK for mac and installed it. But when I run the `dotnet` command from terminal it throws `-bash: dotnet: command not found` error.

I am trying to use the `dotnet new react` to spin up a new .Net Core/React project.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: check this issue in github https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2544

Comment: And this link https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4357

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I've installed dot net core on mac, but didn't find "dotnet" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693683/ive-installed-dot-net-core-on-mac-but-didnt-find-dotnet-command)

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa that link fixed it!

Comment: I solved by editing ~/.zshrc, and putting a new line with:

# Add .NET to $PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/share/dotnet:$PATH"

source: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/6119

Comment: I'm not sure why is it happening. After I installed dotnet sdk 7 x64 version, I had the same error, but then I installed Arm64 version of it and then I was able to use dotnet command line tool again

Answer (score 259):

Make sure your macOS version meets the prerequisites

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/macos-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x

If it does, then after installing via the installer, in a new terminal run this command

`ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/`

Then try `dotnet --version`

hopefully that should work

EDIT:

You might need to add `x64` like so:

`ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet /usr/local/bin/`

Courtesy of Stan in the comments

Comment: It works for me too, it seems that only fails in Catalina.

Comment: The current installer can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/sdk?pivots=os-macos

Comment: For Catania you can download SDK macOS Installer

Comment: Nowadays you have to add `x64` to the path in `dotnet`. Like so `ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: I have installed .net 5/6 on M1 and the PATH in the .zshrc file is `/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/dabeylkhanov/.dotnet`

Comment: i get this problem:
 ln: /usr/local/bin/: No such file or directory

Comment: also works for the raspberry pi but don't forget to do a sudo in front of it

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet /usr/local/bin/

 work with me >> I just added sudo .. and then every thing work.

Comment: On macOS Sonoma I had to add `sudo` to get this to work. Otherwise it works perfectly.

Answer (score 109):

For Mac M1

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

If you add symbolic link to /usr/local/bin/ but you get file exist error.

You can delete the dotnet file at /usr/local/bin/

or

at you finder Shift + ⌘ Command + G and type /usr/local/bin/ , delete the dotnet file in finder.

For M1 and M2, make sure you are installing the Arm64 version -
Marcelo Gonella

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Your post was very helpful for me. I couldn't understand from other comments what I am missing. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome bro , enjoy the pain. :)

Comment: I think I did add the symbolic link not to the x64 version and failed, this solved the issue for me

Comment: For M1 and M2, make sure you are installing the Arm64 version...

Comment: dotnet 6 now offers ARM version for Apple Silicon. If you downloaded the ARM version, use `sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/` command instead to establish a symbolic link.

Comment: I'd echo what Marcelo said if you are on an M1. This fixed the issue in terminal but did not fix any issues in Visual Studio Code i.e. intellisense was failing and the OmniSharp server was not loading (after installing the C# plugin). I delete dotnet SDK completely and reinstalled the Arm54 version. Everything then ran smoothly

Comment: For anyone else who, like me, tried one of the other answers first and kept getting a "file exists" error when trying this answer, you can include the `-f` flag to unlink the existing link and force the new link: `sudo ln -s -f /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet /usr/local/bin/`

Answer (score 47):

Just another way how to successfully install dotnet on a Mac: using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), you can simply run:

```bash
brew install dotnet
```

to have it install. Advantages include automatic updates via `brew upgrade` and less to worry about permissions or any of the workarounds mentioned as solutions before me.

You can find the formula information here: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/dotnet

You also need to download & install **Runtime** from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet)

Comment: To add to confusion , you need this to run `dotnet` from CLI. I was getting  with [this other formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/dotnet), which, I guess is part of installing Visual Studio.

Comment: I **also** had to do: `brew link dotnet`. But you can run `brew doctor` to see if it suggests this.

Comment: As another advantage this was the only way to get intellisense working with VSCode on a Mac, at least for me. I even installed VS Studio which didn't work.  Thank you.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There are a variety of paths possible on macOS, or /user/local/bin/ may not exist.

Answer (score 14):

I solved by editing ~/.zshrc

#Add .NET to $PATH

export PATH="/usr/local/share/dotnet:$PATH"

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the dotnet x64 installer for mac which can be found [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-5.0.403-macos-x64-installer) , use this command

```
sudo su
ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked on my Mac Monterey (M1 chip).

Answer (score 3):

Run `sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/` in the command line, you then should be prompted for your password. This is the solution that worked for me on Mac OS Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 6.x on MacOS I had to run with updated path

```
ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/**x64**/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

Run with sudo if you getting a permission error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

Add entry to .bash_profile

Before:

```
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/libexec:/opt/gradle/gradle-4.10.2/bin
```

After:

```
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/libexec:/opt/gradle/gradle-4.10.2/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet
```

Answer (score 0):

For Rider Users: If you are installed Rider and making development on it, dotnet must be installed on your machine.

For me, I can not found dotnet installation in specified locations; here or microsoft documentations. But Rider makes its own installation.

Go to Rider - Preferences - Buildy, execution, deploymend - Toolset and build and get the path of ".NET CLI executable path". This path specifies the path of sdk installation.

You can run the command below with location you found.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac with M1 (arm) make sure you install the Arm64 version and not the x64 version that you download by default

Answer (score 0):

April 2023, Please open a new terminal before trying the top answer.

macOS 13.3, .NET 7.0
I think it's no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem with the .NET 7 SDK. The issue is that the .NET SDK doesn't configure paths correctly to work with the default ZSH shell:

- It works if you use Bash Shell
- It doesn't work if you use the default ZSH Shell

The problem I've found is that the SDK installs a path value into:

```
# location: /private/etc/paths.d/dotnet-cli-tools
$HOME/.dotnet/tools
```

When running with ZSH `$HOME` (and also `~`)  don't expand properly so the unexpanded value ends up in the path.

The fix that worked for me was to explicitly add the path into this file and then restart the terminal:

```
/Users/YourUsername/.dotnet/tools
```