# No Razor Components Template in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, visual-studio-2019, razor-components

I just installed Visual Studio 2019 (full version) and .NET Core 3.0 Preview 3 so I can test Razor Components. On [Get started with Razor Components page](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/razor-components/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) it says that prerequisites are .NET Core Preview 3 and VS 2019 Preview. I figured that full version (not preview) of VS 2019 would do, but there is no template for Razor Components (I can't even choose .NET Core 3 on that dialog window as it's said on the get started page).

I can still create Razor Components project with `dotnet new razorcomponents`, but I don't understand why is there no template, do I really have to install the preview version of VS 2019 to do so? Or is there some other way I can add the template?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a duplicate as Jimmy pointed out: [ASP.NET Core 3.0 not showing on Visual Studio 2019 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032756/asp-net-core-3-0-not-showing-on-visual-studio-2019-rc)

The solution is to go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Projects and Solutions` -> `.NET Core` and turn on `Use previews of the .NET Core SDK`.

Comment: This option does not exist in VS2019 PRevis 16.2.0. Its now under Environment - Preview Features.