# ASP.NET Core 3.0 not showing on Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise

Tags: asp.net-core

I cannot create an ASP.NET Core 3 project. I do not have the option in the drop-down.

I have reviewed [ASP.NET Core 3.0 not showing on Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032756/asp-net-core-3-0-not-showing-on-visual-studio-2019)

but these "solutions" are not applicable or do not work on my system. I suspect this is because i have VS Enterprise vs a different level. For example my options under "Preview Features" appears completely different than what is shown in the thread mentioned above.

I only have 64-bit SDKs installed. I am running the latest rev of VS 2019. I have the latest .net Core 3.0 preview installed. (as of August 20th, 2019)

I can create a .net Core 3 console app, but if I attempt to create an ASP.NET Core 3 application, I cannot select .net Core 3 as the target, only 2.2.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the dotnet cli?

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the latest RC and preview9 will only work with Visual Studio 2019 v16.3 ... not in 16.2.x. Preview 8 seemed to work fine for me.

Comment: that could be. At the time of my post, only 16.2.3 was available though. It is somewhat of a moot point at this time since 3.0 is slated for release next week. I assume it will integrate automagically into my existing VS Enterprise installation (with updates, etc. I'm sure will be necessary to download and apply.)