# .NET 5 not available in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, .net-5

I have downloaded and installed .NET Core 5.0 SDK (v5.0.100-preview.1) in my Visual Studio 2019.
But it is not available in Target framework.
Am I missing something?

Comment: did you followed [this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-5-0-preview-1/)

Comment: @LazZiya I edited question. It is not available in Project Target framework

Comment: Do you install  the latest preview of Visual Studio 2019 16.6.https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-preview-1/

Comment: @XingZou Yep, My Visual studio version is 16.5.0

Comment: @XingZou Thanks, so helpful

Comment: Now that it's released it should work with VS 2019 latest, (currently 16.8.1) but I had to do a Repair from VS Installer to get the options, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/64826308/8479

Comment: the best answer is: KEEP VS UPDATE

Comment: Related post - [Visual Studio 2019 Not Showing .NET 5 Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65724880/465053)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You need to install the latest preview of **Visual Studio 2019 16.8**, refer to

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-preview-1/

You also need to explicitly enable preview versions within Visual Studio itself:

[image: enable previews]

Then you should see it:

[image]

Comment: I have Visual Studio 16.6.0 and .NET SDK 5.0.100-preview.4.20258.7, and .NET 5 is not available as target framework choice.

Comment: @AlexI - you also need to [enable preview versions in Visual Studio itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032756/asp-net-core-3-0-not-showing-on-visual-studio-2019).

Comment: I used 16.7, uninstalled, installed 16.6.2, enabled preview. Not working. I will try with 16.6.0

Comment: There isn't an option to "use previews of .NET Core SDK" in Visual Studio 16.7 preview. Do I need to download 16.6.0 Preview (and can someone provide a link?)

Comment: there's 2 different builds. vs 2019 and vs 2019 preview.  You do not need to enable the 'use previews' feature in vs 2019 preview build, because it is enabled as part of the build.

Comment: Now you need to install Visual Studio 2019 **(v16.8, Preview 3)**.

Comment: wait that still has "Core" in its name, well it is still preview but seeing all the info on the release news, I thought it will be "ASP .NET 5" only

Comment: apparently the version 16.8 cannot be installed in vs 2019 community

Comment: I can't see it as well. Installed the latest .Net5 SDK as well as enabling Preview SDK on Visual Studio, as well as restarted my PC. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 34):

Specs: VS Version 16.8.0

Target Version of .Net Core: 5.0

***You must have version 16.8.0 in order to have .Net Core 5.0***

If you still have problems with Visual Studio not showing .Net Core 5.0 in Visual Studio version 16.8.0 (and assuming you downloaded the .NET Core 5.0 SDK for Visual Studio), well, apparently (and correct me if I'm wrong) it is now called just .Net 5.0, omitting the Core.

[image]

After selecting .NET 5.0, I was able to install other libraries which are currently version 5.0+ and dependent on .NET Core 5.0+

Is the new name intentional? Anyways, here some evidence of this working (I was able to install the newest version of Newtonsoft and Entity Framework for .Net Core):

[image]

Funny enough, when I try to create a new .Net Core project, the version shows up as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 20):

I upgraded my version of Visual studio from 16.7.x to 16.8.1. I expected NET 5 to be listed as a target framework, but it was not.

I had previously created projects in 16.8 preview 6 using RC1.

Visual Studio Install did not list .NET 5 as an individual component either. I then downloaded and installed the x64 SDK. Still no luck. .NET5 was still missing as a target framework for VS 16.8.x

Today I opened VS Installer and from the **More** dropdown menu selected **Repair** . The repair process took 25-30 minutes to run, but now .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 are listed in all the usual places.

Norm

Comment: I also needed to do a Repair before I got the .net 5 options.

Comment: I confirm that starting Visual Installer and selecting repair finally fix the issue.

Comment: I went up to 16.11 without any luck, and all the Repair install did for me was delete my settings >.< It would be nice to know which setting or DB where is responsible for showing or not showing the newer versions

Answer (score 10):

Maybe a bit late to the party.
Please note that if you've selected a 'regular' **.NET Framework** application you won't see the .NET 5.0 Framework option.
This is only visible in .NET Core project styles.

Comment: What the... Why? O.o
So even now there is no way to utilize official components of .NET 5.0, like the modern "upgraded" Folder Browser, in a .NET Framework app?

Answer (score 8):

Try to set it in your .csproj file. Right click (maybe unload) and edit (within a PropertyGroup-element):

```xml
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: You do not need to unload the project to edit the .csproj file.

Answer (score 3):

Targeting .NET 5 (rc2) doesn't work smoothly in VS Version 16.8.0 Preview 6.0

I could only target .NET 5 by manually changing the .csproj file, and adding:

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted to create a solution, .NET 5 was not available, even when I have it installed. What I did to fix this was:

1. When you are creating the project, select the last version (in my case .NET Core 3.1)
2. When the project is created, right click on the project and select the *Properties* option.
3. In the *Application* tab, select the *Target Framework* you want.

[image: Example]