# Visual Studio 2019 Not Showing .NET 5 Framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-5

I've been trying to upgrade my ASP.NET project in Visual Studio from the .NET 4.7.2 framework to .NET 5. I can't figure out what the problem is, because I've tried several different things and none of them have made .NET 5 available.

1. I've installed the latest version of Visual Studio Community 2019,
   version 16.8.4.
2. I've installed .NET 5.0.102. The Command Prompt confirms this when I
   type `dotnet --version`.
3. In Visual Studio's *Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features*,
   I've enabled "Use previews of the .NET Core SDK", and restarted the
   program.
4. In Visual Studio Installer, I've selected *Modify > Individual
   components*. The .NET 5.0 Runtime is installed, but there's nothing
   listed for a .NET Framework 5; the highest listed is 4.8.
5. I've tried restarting the program and my computer, and reinstalling both Visual Studio and the .NET 5.0.102 framework.

The *About* window in Visual Studio says that my .NET version is 4.8.040. The most recent .NET framework that I can select in my project is 4.7.2. Creating a new project doesn't offer a newer version either.

I want to work with C# 9.0, but my project is stuck in 7.3. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you installed .NET 5.0.102 (step 2), did you install the [.NET **SDK**](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks)?. Run `dotnet --info`, and see what's listed under ".NET SDKs installed:". You need the SDK to develop software: it includes things like the compiler, which aren't included in the runtime

Comment: What does `dotnet --list-sdks` show you (--info will give you this and more, but this much is crucial)?  (Don't comment -- [edit] it into the post.)  Also, terminology: There's no ".NET Framework 5.0"  What's called ".NET Framework" ended at 4.8.  .NET Core became just ".NET" at 5.0, skipping 4.x to avoid confusion with .NET Framework.

Comment: That said, upgrading from ASP.NET (.NET Framework 1.0-4.8) to ASP.NET Core is not trivial and I haven't seen or heard of a project upgrade command in Visual Studio. Even if you have everything installed, it's going to be a rewrite, the scope of which will depend greatly on what technologies you're using. MVC and Web API functionality will be easier to reimplement on ASP.NET Core, but there are non-trivial differences. WebForms simply isn't supported.

Comment: This may go without saying, but make sure you reboot your machine after installing the SDK.

Comment: Refer to [this tutorial](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/install) to check if you can create a .NET5 via command. If the .NET 5 has been installed, when you create a "ASP.NET Core Web Application", you can modify the `Target framework` to `.NET 5` in `Project => Properties => Application` tag. Here is a blog: [Announcing ASP.NET Core in .NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/announcing-asp-net-core-in-net-5/) you can refer to.

Comment: to get work around, try out with lower version, by following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65724880/visual-studio-2019-not-showing-net-5-framework, Or update VS version greater than 16.8.0 by using help option in visual studio, if problem in help follow this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.NET 5 is not a direct replacement for .NET Framework 4.5+. If you try to create a new project and choose .NET Framework, then you will be able to choose for example 4.7, 4.8, but not .NET 5.

You will only find .NET 5 in projects which are .NET Core type.

In summary - you can't switch .NET Framework project to .NET 5 using simple Project Property window. You have to rewrite the application to .NET 5 - which is indeed the next version after .NET Core 3.1.

Regarding your question:

> I want to work with C# 9.0, but my project is stuck in 7.3. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Please look at the [C# language versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#defaults) page. C# 8.0 is available for `netstandard2.1` which is not supported by .NET Framework. Same thing with C# 9.0.

[What is .NET 5 in comparison to .NET Core and .NET Framework](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/) you can read on Microsoft Dev Blog.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 5 is really the next version of .NET Core, not .NET Framework. .NET Framework is a legacy product that will only see minor maintenance fixes, like security patches, in the future.

Moving from Framework to Core involves dealing with all kinds of breaking changes and is more complicated than simply changing your project's target framework.

For that purpose, Microsoft has a [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/) for ASP.NET, which you can read to learn what you need to change in your project.