# WPF App (.NET) for .NET 5 is not available

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, .net-5

I am using vs 2019 version 16.9.4 (april 2021) and wanted to create a WPF App (.NET) project using .NET 5 as described at Microsoft's tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/desktop/wpf/get-started/create-app-visual-studio?view=netdesktop-5.0) (january 2021).
Unfortunately, only WPF App (.NET Framework), but not WPF App (.NET) is available in the menu as shown in the tutorial. I also checked the installer for any missing components without success.

Comment: Did you install the [SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) or the appropriate VS workloads?

Comment: Yes, but can't see it at the main menu for creating a new WPF App.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2019 Not Showing .NET 5 Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65724880/visual-studio-2019-not-showing-net-5-framework)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But it says that you can't switch from Framework to NET 5. That's why I was looking for WPF App (NET) instead of WPF App (Framework).

Comment: Quite confusing, but I found the solution. You have to choose „Create a new project“ and then simply „WPF Application“ (without any .NET or xaml tag)