# How to create .Net 5.0 Class Library project in Visual Studio 2019 16.8.1?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, class-library

I can not see the Class Library(.NET) option on **Add a New Project** window in Visual Studio 16.8.1. How can I create a Class Library (.NET) project? (Not .Net Core or .Net Framework)

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. Create a new .NET Core library and set the target framework to 5

Comment: Create a new .NET Core class library, and change `<TargetFramework>` to `net5.0` in the csproj. .NET 5 is just rebranded .NET Core. I imagine the templates will catch up at some point.

Comment: Any class library you create that targets `net5.0` can only be used by .NET 5 and above though, not even .NET Core 3.1. If you want to use that library with 3.1 you should target .NET Standard 2.1

Comment: Libraries usually target the lowest acceptable version, not the highest, so that they are usable in more situations.

Comment: @Dialecticus that's an over-simplification of a complex area; there are costs to targeting older frameworks, and I don't just mean the code compromises due to missing features - I mean things like "has anyone actually tested it on (older framework)?". There are many good reasons to limit libraries to more *recent* frameworks. If I was starting a library from scratch, I'd probably target net5.0 until there was a good reason to multi-target, at which time I might consider adding netcoreapp3.1; anything lower: would need serious consideration

Comment: @MarcGravell: I think there's significant merit to limiting to the latest *LTS* version. I'd personally probably start a new library with netstandard2.1, unless I needed anything from either a more recent version or from netcoreapp3.1.

Comment: @JonSkeet that's a topic we could happily discuss for hours over some drinks in a non-Covid world :) my next two questions would be: "OK, so what frameworks other than .NET Core 3.1 implement .NET Standard 2.1?" and "and have you *actually tested* on that[/those] framework[s]?". There's also another side benefit of significantly simplifying the dependency tree - you can lose a *lot* of package refs by targeting the framework rather than the API standard. I agree re LTS though: https://twitter.com/marcgravell/status/1327304774291779585

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yup, let's grab those drinks when we can. May well be around the time .NET 6 comes out anyway. (For now, I need to keep targeting netstandard20 and net461 anyway... customers...)

Comment: I have the same issue. I see .NET Core, .NET Standard, .NET Framework but nothing that indicates .NET 5 - it would be nice if you could filter by version.

Comment: [.NET 5 not available in Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60843091/net-5-not-available-in-visual-studio-2019) and [Tutorial: Create a .NET class library using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the project templates are still giving you .NET Core 3.1 as the highest option, and the project properties options aren't allowing what you want - it isn't a problem: simply right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and select "Edit Project File", to edit the .csproj, and you can change the target framework - for example, from

```xml
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

to

```xml
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

to target .NET 5, or

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

to multi-target.

Comment: I like how the current generation seems to have no idea why it's called *Visual* Studio. I don't know if Microsoft sees having to edit the project file by hand as an advancement. But it makes no sense to me.

Comment: @JonathanWood and most changes *can* be made via the UI; I'm not concerned if some niche things can't - and honestly, there shouldn't be any "magic" - it is worth taking the time to know what the UI is doing

Comment: The more you can learn, the better. But the "visual" relates to productivity. I should be able to create a project that uses the latest framework from Microsoft without manually editing the project file. I mean, otherwise, why have menus? Just give us a big command windows and we'll type everything in. That would eliminate almost all the "magic."

Comment: @JonathanWood: To me, since Visual C++ 6.0, it was about double clicking a button in the dialog editor and getting to the OnButton_Click-code - and then not questioning "Visual" again :D

Answer (score 23):

In Visual Studio 2019, I believe it needs to be 16.8+, you can enable the preview feature `Show all .NET Core templates in the New project dialog`.

[image]

Go Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Preview Features -> Show all .NET Core templates in the New project dialog (Requires Restart)

Then close Visual Studio and reopen it. Now from the new project dialog there should be a `Class Library` with a C# in the tags.

[image]

From here, click `Next`. Fill out where you want it to be made and what to call it as you normally would.

[image]

Then click `Next` again. This will bring you to a new screen that has a drop down for the `Target Framework`.

[image]

Set this to `.NET 5.0` and click `Create`. This creates a .NET 5.0 class library and opens it in the IDE.

Comment: Great answer. Just to add on to this, an updated version of Visual Studio is neccessary, as you also pointed out.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/target-frameworks-missing/1208780

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following steps to create a Class Library project based on .NET 5.0.

First, please download the .NET 5.0 SDK from [Download .NET 5.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) and install it.

Second, please use the following command to create the project.

```
dotnet new Classlib -n Testlib
```

[image]

Third, please find the specific path and open the project `Testlib.csproj`.

Finally, you can see a class library based on .NET 5.0.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to create `.NET Core` library and then simply change `Target framework` in project properties. .NET 5.0 is available!

[image]

But note, if you create `.NET Framework` library, the options to change to `.NET Core` or `.NET 5.0` will not be there.

It seems like Visual Studio is treating `.NET 5.0` as the latest version of `.NET Core`. It's in the same bin.

This is with Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8.4