# Missing Test Project Type in VS 2019 .NET 5

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have a project targeting .NET 5 asp.net Core in VS 2019.

I keep seeing reference to a project type that seems to be missing from my instance, "MSTest Test Project (.NET Core)"

The previous .NET project type isn't compatible with Core.

Is there a something specific in the VS install I need to go back and select?

Comment: I can't really tell what it is you're asking.  Is your main project trying to reference MSTest in some way? [MSTest](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/) is a nuget package.  You should only need to have this nuget included in your Test Project.

Comment: Can't you find the library? You can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64874414/how-to-create-net-5-0-class-library-project-in-visual-studio-2019-16-8-1

Comment: In VS, Add Project, the "MSTest Test Project (.NET Core)" project type is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently they just renamed it.

> Starting in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9, the MSTest project
> template name changed from MSTest Unit Test Project (.NET Core) to
> Unit Test Project.

[Found at](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-managed-code?view=vs-2019)