# The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator' specified could not be found. .net core 5 MacOS

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-cli

I'm working on macOS Big Sur and Visual Studio .net core 5.
I think the issues started after allowing Visual Studio to install updates (I wasn't expecting any issues), after a few hours `dotnet` command stopped working.

I found out that it's a known issue on M1 Macs, when dotnet stops working and that the recommended version to work with - 5.0.402.
I unistalled dotnet and installed the recommended version.

Commands to uninstall dotnet (require script file):

```
chmod +x dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh 
sudo ./dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh
sudo rm -r /etc/dotnet
```

After installing the newer version(5.0.402) my project still doesn't works and I'm getting this error in Visual Studio:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk/6.0.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props(14,38): error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator' specified could not be found.
```

I was thinking to uninstall the latest SDK but not sure if it's a good idea and may cause to additional issues with VisualStudio.

```
$ ./dotnet-core-uninstall list
```

Output (from dotnet-core-uninstall tool):

```
This tool cannot uninstall versions of the runtime or SDK that are installed using zip/scripts. The versions that can be uninstalled with this tool are:

.NET Core SDKs:
  5.0.402  (x64)  [Used by Visual Studio for Mac. Specify individually or use —-force to remove]

.NET Core Runtimes:
  5.0.11  (x64)  [Used by Visual Studio for Mac or SDKs. Specify individually or use —-force to remove]
```

**Please advise how to solve this issue.**

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 12):

Upon install of VS2022 (v17.0 - build8989) on x64 Mac, I got this error but did not get this error when building from command line.

Things tried to fix this:

- Followed the above instructions (multiple times)
- deleted (3x) every trace of Mono, Xamarin, NuGet, DotNet, and VisualStudio from my system and reinstalled VS2022
- Setting the `MSBuildEnableWorkloadResolver = false` environment variable
- lots of reboots

None of the above worked.  What was I missing?  **I was setting the `MSBuildEnableWorkloadResolver = false` environment variable the wrong way.**

If you turn on Diagnostic log verbosity, the first thing listed in the build log will be the environment variables used for the build.  The way that I was trying to set this environment variable was not effecting VisualStudio!

After a little bit of research, I learned that the most systemic way to set environment variables in MacOS is through launchctl:

```
 % launchctl setenv MSBuildEnableWorkloadResolver false
```

The old approach of systemically setting environmental variables was via ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist . However, that approach was removed in OS X Lion.  Setting environment variables in the traditional Unix way (`.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.zprofile`, `.zshenv`, etc) only applies to shells and will not work for applications.

Comment: I used this answer to make the MSBuildEnableWorkloadResolver variable available on system start up to all the applications on MacOS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/588442/6846888 . Can you include this on your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Had this happen to me recently on **Windows 10**. My issue was that I installed .NET 8 SDK manually (not through Visual Studio Installer) and Rider started failing to load projects in my solution with this error.

**I fixed it by using MSBuild from the SDK folder and not the one included with Visual Studio.**

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that worked for me to solve this issue.

1. I removed all dotnet components following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=macos).
2. I installed SDK 5.0.404
   After installation `dotnet` command didn't work.
3. I followed recommendations from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030531/dotnet-command-not-found-in-mac) and it solved my issue.
   I removed existing dotnet file and recreated it.

Hope it will be helpful for someone.