# dotnet command not found and permission denied

Tags: .net, macos, terminal

So I was trying to download.NET 6.0 for Mac, but after I installed it, I couldn't verify it was installed because my terminal couldn't find the dotnet command. When I looked at this previous Stackflow link: [I've installed dot net core on mac, but didn't find "dotnet" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693683/ive-installed-dot-net-core-on-mac-but-didnt-find-dotnet-command) , I was denied permission for some of the solutions suggested. How do I get my terminal to find the dotnet command?

First I tried this

> ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet/usr/local/bin/

then this

> ln -s/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet

The second one worked, but I still can't find the dotnet command.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the space in the command suggested in the answer you mentioned:

```
ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

`ln -s` creates a symbolic link on the file system and it has two arguments: source and destination. If you're more familiar with Windows world, this command creates a shortcut.